# git subcommand VS git --option

Tags: git

git stash list >> will list all the stashes

git tag --list >> will list all the tags

but why it is "list" in the first command and "--list" in the second command? It is confusing for me (say you do "git tag list", then you actually create a tag called "list"). Does this apply for "stash" commands only(as all stash commands seem to be without --)? What is the logic behind this?

Edit:

after Charles Bailey reply I found that it is better to give the question more general sense so it becomes more useful. So, is there any convention used by git to distinguish between "subcommands" (like `git stash list`) and "options" (like `git tag --list`)?

thanks for contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the reason for this is because `git tag` takes an *argument* -- as opposed to a subcommand -- which should be able to be called anything you want. You should definitely be able to call a tag "*list*" if you so choose. Therefore `git tag` must hide its "subcommands" (or *options*) behind flags instead of subcommands.

The arguments to `git stash` are more strictly defined, so it is able to use true subcommands.

Comment: I think this is the best explanation so far for why git tag uses --list, but it raises the question of why then git stash doesn't use --list for consistency instead of list.

Comment: My guess is because it would make `git stash` inconsistent with itself, where then `--list` would act as a subcommand but provided to the command as an option, which isn't really the intention. I suppose. :) Edit: Also, `git stash list` has its own options.

Comment: [1] That would have been satisfying for me if it is only "tag" that has this pattern but the fact that it is not. Look at other commends, git commit, for example, has many options that follow the --option pattern and doesn't have any that utilizes subcommands. Also, it is true that you should be able to call your tag anything including "list" but even with "git-stash" you could give it a name this way: git stash -a "list"!

Comment: [2] That said, I still want to say that I give tag & stash as examples but I'm looking for a more general answer.. ex. in powershell, you will find that all commends follow this convention: "noun-verb -option"; is there any convention for git commands that explains the example of tag, stash & the rest?

Comment: I think the problem with git is that it wasn't developed as one cohesive program from the start. It was developed as many different small utilities that have their own conventions that work best for *them*, not that work best as one consistent whole. That's why git suffers from these inconsistencies, and one of the reasons why people run into problems when treating it as one monolithic SCM, rather than many different utilities under the same namespace ("git").

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's simply that the English word `tag` can be used as a verb, so it feels natural to say `git tag v1` and expect it to actually tag the current checkout `v1`.

The thing is, you can add aliases to make just about any syntax you want.  When you get tired of typing `git checkout` in full, make an alias.  Try searching for `handy git aliases`.

Comment: Aliases would solve this but I am looking for general answer that explains stash, tag, and the rest of many git commands that share the same issue. I guess what I am looking for is the "naming convention" (if any) that is used by git to distinguish subcommands from --options. Why "list" was set as a subcommand in "stash" & as an --option in "tag"? powershell, for example, uses "noun-verb -options"; is there any convention used by git? Please look at my comments [1] & [2] on Victor Zamanian as well. Thanks all for contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is that `stash` has multiple sub commands (create, list, apply, drop, pop, etc.) so the first word is (usually) a `stash` subcommand and not an option. `stash` is like `bundle`, `remote` and `submodule` in this respect.

`tag` is just a "normal" command, it only lists (the default), or creates tags (lightweight or full). As "list" is the default action and you don't usually need to supply, it is an option and hence the `--`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any convention used by Git to distinguish between "subcommands" (like `git stash list`) and "options" (like `git tag --list`)?

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) illustrates the difference between subcommand and option, and introduces the "subcommand" mode to parse-options API, updating the command line parser of Git commands with subcommands.

See [commit 8f9d80f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f9d80f6c06369b563c76ec46c462e740a1a2cf0), [commit 0d330a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d330a53f31a0885954ac48c5e6d24efd3969039), [commit ecd2d3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecd2d3efe04c982eb9b95a2997841634f6a54e45) (25 Aug 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 398c4ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/398c4ff582646b099eb1f3b14a525dfe5eeb5420), [commit 2b057d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b057d97d796d9192ec899a2109924cabba23ba6), [commit 1c3502b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c3502b198a211031619ce22870490b1498c15dd), [commit b26a412](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b26a412f1e96e40c419001991486cced837679a6), [commit 729b973](https://github.com/git/git/commit/729b97332b05564133e4039fbab9f694c25097a2), [commit 54ef767](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54ef7676bab9292c041e6ada73bb48a4c261c71b), [commit bf0a6b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf0a6b65fcdb919ed27d0b77f0adfd65d84ea691), [commit f83736c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f83736ce9d3c76cd5a05d1e647cf5cf0a026f0b6), [commit 0350954](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0350954482bca6accd7b4ad072a1bdb83651b376), [commit 1c3b051](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c3b05170a02adf894a33bc888b0fb730ee7f236), [commit aef7d75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aef7d75e5809eda765bbe407c7f8e0f8617f0fd0), [commit fa83cc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa83cc834dad896e1a48cdea588e690692690b69), [commit dc9f988](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc9f98832b849ee05b84bad1a55f5e04b82d0520), [commit a9126b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9126b92a2adddb58522a342cdbaf0aec4d879bf), [commit 99d86d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99d86d60e59e11cbc46766346e3e379164a6e4df), [commit 80882bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80882bc5e7143a0c3823b5a398fd76c9138437ef), [commit c1b117d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1b117d31ca9b09444f14092c35d092f3330823e), [commit 31a66c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31a66c196435d12e9562ce89da8646016ec8b1e7), [commit 9e4658d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e4658d5c6917b926a299a55ff8b18ca256e301c), [commit 66fa6e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66fa6e8ed8bcfff6708d7bceed4c2b9e4050ebe7) (19 Aug 2022) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d528044](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d528044c83cc1f5fb925fbb043110f5fb0382f99), 01 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`parse-options`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa83cc834dad896e1a48cdea588e690692690b69): add support for parsing subcommands
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>

> Several Git commands have subcommands to implement mutually exclusive "operation modes", and they usually parse their subcommand argument with a bunch of if-else if statements.
>
> Teach parse-options to handle subcommands as well, which will result in shorter and simpler code with consistent error handling and error messages on unknown or missing subcommand, and it will also make possible for our Bash completion script to handle subcommands programmatically.
>
> The approach is guided by the following observations:
>
> - Most subcommands are implemented in dedicated functions, and most of those functions either have a signature matching the
>   '`int cmd_foo(int argc, const char **argc, const char *prefix)`' signature of builtin commands or can be trivially converted to that signature, because they miss only that last prefix parameter or have no parameters at all.
> - Subcommand arguments only have long form, and they have no double dash prefix, no negated form, and no description, and they don't take any arguments, and can't be abbreviated.
> - There must be exactly one subcommand among the arguments, or zero if the command has a default operation mode.
> - All arguments following the subcommand are considered to be arguments of the subcommand, and, conversely, arguments meant for the subcommand may not precede the subcommand.
>
> If a command has a default operation mode, '`fn`' should be initialized to the function implementing that mode, and `parse_options()` should be invoked with the `PARSE_OPT_SUBCOMMAND_OPTIONAL` flag.
> In this case `parse_options()` won't error out when not finding any subcommands, but will return leaving '`fn`' unchanged.
> Note that if that default operation mode has any `--options`, then the `PARSE_OPT_KEEP_UNKNOWN_OPT` flag is necessary as well (otherwise `parse_options()` would error out upon seeing the unknown option meant to the default operation mode).
>
> - If the command with subcommands has a default operation mode, then all arguments to the command must precede the arguments of the subcommand.
>   AFAICT we don't have any commands where this makes a difference, because in those commands either only the command accepts any arguments ('notes' and 'remote'), or only the default subcommand ('`reflog`' and '`stash`'), but never both.
> - To support handling subcommands programmatically in our Bash completion script, git cmd `--git-completion-helper` will now list both subcommands and regular `--options`, if any.
>   This means that the completion script will have to separate subcommands (i.e.
>   words without a double dash prefix) from `--options` on its own, but that's rather easy to do, and it's not much work either, because the number of subcommands a command might have is rather low, and those commands accept only a single `--option` or none at all.
>
> Note that this change doesn't affect the behavior of our Bash completion script, because when completing the `--option` of a command with subcommands, e.g. for '`git notes --<TAB>`', then all subcommands will be filtered out anyway, as none of them will match the word to be completed starting with that double dash prefix.

`technical/api-parse-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa83cc834dad896e1a48cdea588e690692690b69/Documentation/technical/api-parse-options.txt#L52-L78):

> Subcommands are special in a couple of ways:
>
> - Subcommands only have long form, and they have no double dash prefix, no
>   negated form, and no description, and they don't take any arguments, and
>   can't be abbreviated.
> - There must be exactly one subcommand among the arguments, or zero if the
>   command has a default operation mode.
> - All arguments following the subcommand are considered to be arguments of
>   the subcommand, and, conversely, arguments meant for the subcommand may
>   not preceed the subcommand.
>
> Therefore, if the options array contains at least one subcommand and
> `parse_options()` encounters the first dashless argument, it will either:
>
> - stop and return, if that dashless argument is a known subcommand, setting
>   `value` to the function pointer associated with that subcommand, storing
>   the name of the subcommand in `argv[0]`, and leaving the rest of the
>   arguments unprocessed, or
> - stop and return, if it was invoked with the `PARSE_OPT_SUBCOMMAND_OPTIONAL`
>   flag and that dashless argument doesn't match any subcommands, leaving
>   `value` unchanged and the rest of the arguments unprocessed, or
> - show error and usage, and abort.

Answer (score -3):

Because git is `the stupid content tracker`, if you don't believe me, read the `NAME` section of `man git`. There's no logic behind its commands and command parameters, they are often inconsistent, but nobody cares :(

Comment: This is a very poor answer in my opinion, if one at all. There is logic behind this, and there are now a couple of answers given. Stating that "nobody cares" is evidently false since somebody is asking a question regarding it, but apart from that the statement is ambiguous with regards to who you are talking about. Nobody [in the git development team] or [who is a user of git] or [in general]?

Comment: Nobody in the git development team and contributors. As for logic behind commands and parameters, there is nice blog post http://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/.

Comment: Perhaps because there is logic behind the way things work now.

Comment: That blog post is much more humorous than it is accurate. :P

Comment: Of course it's humorous, but it shows at least 5 cases where git is not consistent. `git stash list` vs `git tag --list` is 6th. Of course one may think of many possible reasons why it's so, but it's just because nobody [in the git development team] cares for consistency. Also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor, replace "malice" with "sovereign plan".

Comment: The reason Git commands are sometimes inconsistent is well known: contrary to many systems, Git was developed "from the bottom up". That is, Linus Torvalds initially sketched Git as a very low-level toolkit, *on top of which a full-fledged SCM could be built.* Instead Git itself was quickly improved to become such an SCM, but that "extensive" approach to its development persisted, so Git became more of less useful for mere mortals somewhere about v1.6 when it received various UI facelifts.

Comment: I mean, everyone writing another dumb blog post about inconsistencies could instead pull their neck from their chair and write a shiny new "right" SCM on top of the Git plumbing level commands, engeneered to provide a consistent UI. But writing blog posts is so much easier, you know... :-) (As is writing SO comments, I admit it.)

Comment: Indeed. Also, what I was saying was that several of those "5 cases" are exaggerated and sometimes inconsistent and inaccurate themselves, not taking into account the *logic* behind the design, inconsistencies aside. The 6th included.